# Notation in music score

Tags: piano

What is this notation with the short line in the music score?[image]

Comment: It *could* be a tremolo-like notation (each note is a repetition of duration indicated by the stroke + beam), but it usually uses oblique lines, not horizontal, and it actually doesn't make a lot of sense as written like this Do you have a bigger picture of the whole piece/example/excercise? From what is it taken, and for what instruments?

Comment: ^ and that shows the importance of having a searchable title or description, not just "what's this?" with a picture;\